# In Austria, is a disclaimer that your device is not a medical device enough even if all your other material suggests it is a medical device?

Tags: medical, austria

This company ["powerinsole"](https://powerinsole.com) in Austria makes wild claims about the scientific merits of it's medical device "powerinsole". It is a device they claim uses electro resonance to transmit information from chip storage to the cells in your feet. The claim is dubious yet the overall tone of the website is science/science/science. There are links to papers and supposed endorsements from prestigious research organisations, one of which has publicly rejected the claims made by the company.

[image]

https://www.powerinsole.com/science-en/?lang=en#university-of-salzburg

Notwithstanding the attempt to veneer the product with scientific credibility, at the bottom of each page there is the disclaimer.

> Please note that despite its repeated success in various fields, the Powerinsole is not a medical
> product! In the event of illness, Powerinsole is by no means a substitute for going to the doctor, nor
> does Powerinsole replace medication prescribed by a doctor or medical treatment!

My question is:

Is this disclaimer by powerinsole enough in Austria to protect the company from prosecution for selling medical devices without the correct authorization?

Comment: The tone of the site is pseudo science/technobabel/unscientific bull excrement

Comment: Yes but they took the effort to get a research paper produced by the university of Salzburg and then misrepresent it's results as well as other documents from other institutions. It's well designed technobabble, at least to the average consumer.

Comment: This looks like a case where EU law would apply - regardless of the extra protection Austrian law may offer consumers, this already appears to be in violation of EU consumer law.

Comment: @MSalters Do you know who I can approach to get this looked into? Is there a department which will take such things seriously? I've already been in touch with the Austrian bureau of consumer affairs but they said they only act if an actual customer or competitor complains.

Comment: You'd have to check how Austria implemented "REGULATION (EU) 2017/745  of 5 April 2017 on medical devices". The regulation itself already warns that edge cases too are covered: "Certain groups of products for which **a manufacturer claims only** an aesthetic or another non-medical purpose but which are similar to medical devices in terms of functioning and risks profile should be covered by this Regulation". I'd not expect a general "Consumer Affairs" dept to be very pro-active; a dept that regulates _real_ medical devices will have a much stricter vies of such fake devices.